# How can I implement logging in python for multiple modules

Tags: python, oop, logging

**Env Summary:**

Hi, I have a Python project, where I request some information from a storage system and display this on screen.

**Env:**

module executer 
Module rest has a class RestThreePar
Module storagebox has a class StorageBox
Module locater has a class Locater

**Problem:**

I want to implement a single module/class for logging for the hole project, which needs to log stuff to 4 different files (each module has it's own log file). When I import logging separately for each module it works like expected but whenever I try to make a separate class and import that one (like from logger import Logger) it goes wrong (I am not sure but it looks like it writes one line multiple times in the files).

I am not a developer and don't know what to do next.

I have tried to use the python documentation but had no success.
https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/logging-cookbook.html

```
import logging
import os

class Logger:
    def __init__(self, cls_name, file):
        self.cls_name = cls_name
        current_dir = os.getcwd()
        self.file = f'{current_dir}/logs/{file}'

    def log(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger(self.cls_name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s,%(levelname)s,%(name)s,%(message)s')

        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(self.file)
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        return logger

    def log_info(self, msg):
        logger = self.log()
        logger.info(msg)

    def log_exception(self, msg):
        logger = self.log()
        logger.exception(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Comment: You shouldn't write your own logger class, you should use `get_logger(__main__)` to get an instance. What you want to write / configure are handlers that you register at the start of the program.

Comment: @Arne, thanks I adjusted my way. now it's working much better, the only problem that remains is that now the formatter is not applied for 2 of the 4 modules